# Getting selected item in Items control

Tags: c#, wpf

I know that there is no selected item property in Items Control
So I am trying to do the things via command parameter:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Vrapper.myVM.Names}" x:Name="NamesCtr">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding}">
                                            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ElementName=NamesCtr, Path=DataContext.Vrapper.myVM.LoadCommand}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
                                                </Style>
                                            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
```

And command is not working =(

in myVM there is:

```
...
loadCommand = new VrapCommand(load);
...

public void load(Object obj)
{
    string chosenName = obj as string;
}
```

if I will try the following DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=NamesCtr,   Path=Path=DataContext.Vrapper.myVM.LoadCommand}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

the load function is hit (the command is working) ,  but I need to pass this param (name of selected menu item) to function.

Comment: If you need the selected item. Why not use a control better suited for it?

Comment: Found simple solution just CommandParameter = "{Binding}"